# Use entry from /etc/hosts in PostgreSQL JDBC connection URL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, hostname

Is it valid to use a dynamic name entry from the `/etc/hosts` file in the `host` part of a JDBC connection URL of the form `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Host lookups are performed using the underlying OS which will check the hosts file.

Comment: Thanks. Before putting everything into question, it helps to look elsewhere.